# Why css3 slideshow does not work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow using css3. I have followed a few tutorials:

- http://themarklee.com/2013/10/16/simple-crossfading-slideshow-css/
- http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/

And I've arrived at the following code:

```
<div id="right-leftSide"> 
    <div id="leftPic">
        <img id="chefPic" src="images/chef.jpg">
        <img id ="recipeImage" src="images/people.jpg">
        <img src="images/recipe1.jpg" id="recipeImage2">
        <img id ="recipeImage" src="images/people.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#leftPic{
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftPic img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

}

#leftPic img:nth-of-type(1){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 18s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(2){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 12s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(3){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 6s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(4){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 0s infinite;
}



@keyframes fadeInOut{
    0% {
opacity: 1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    92%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

However, when I create the `keyframes`, how is timing determined? The examples use a percentage, but I don't understand what that *means*. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The timing is determined in the parameters of the #leftPic nth child, in this case '24s'

Comment: x% of the time you have specified for the animation, in this case 24s (92% = 22.08s)

Comment: @xDaevax I am sorry, but I am still confused? I know the time is 24s and every image is 6s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I created a fiddle to demonstrate the animation using some stock images.  I also included webkit compatibility in the fiddle so it works on chrome and other webkit browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/Kfw3L/

Example:

```
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(1){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 18s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 24s 18s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(2){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 12s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 24s 12s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(3){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 6s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 24s 6s infinite;
}
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(4){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 24s 0s infinite;
}
```

See this link which explains the syntax more clearly.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Basically, the animation duration is 24 seconds based on your code and the delay is 18, 12, 6, and 0 seconds respectively.

So on a timeline, at 0% (or 0 seconds) the image will be 100% opaque.  By the time it reaches 25% or 6 seconds, the image will be 0% visible (transparent).  This will be on a delay of 18s for the first image, 12 for the second, etc...  By the time it reaches 24 seconds (or 100%) the image will once again be 100% opaque.

So for your animations,

- First Image (4th image in list): no delay, will last for 24 seconds (finish time is 24s from load).
- Second Image (3rd in list): 6 second delay, will last for 24 seconds (finish time is 30s from load).
- Third Image (2nd in list): 12 second delay, will last for 24 seconds (finish time is 36s from load).
- Fourth Image (1st in list): 18 second delay, will last for 24 seconds (finish time is 42s from load).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are declaring the timing of the animation,

```
#leftPic img:nth-of-type(1){
    animation: fadeInOut 24s 18s infinite;
}
../
```

In this section of your code you are saying at this percent of the amount of time into the animation I want this opacity to be set.

```
@keyframes fadeInOut{
    0% {
opacity: 1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    92%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The definition of `opacity`
Opacity - the condition of lacking transparency or translucence; opaqueness.

So if you state the time for the animation is `100 seconds` then 10% `{ opacity: 1; }` at `10 seconds` you would have `{ opacity: 1;`